# Difference between: "both can be viewed as [a task / tasks]…“

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, comparison

What is the difference in comparing plural nouns to a singular noun or a plural noun?

I've seen several versions of comparing noun A to noun B when the noun A is plural. Some sentences use the singular for B others use plural form. For example I recently saw this one:

> We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common, and in particular **both can be viewed as a task** in function approximation.
>
> Source: [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Elements_of_Statistical_Learning/yPfZBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22these+two+tasks%22+%22in+particular+both+can+be+viewed+as+a+task%22&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover)

As I can see it's perfectly okay to change the above sentence as: "...both can be viewed as **tasks**..." without changing the meaning of the sentence (at least to me).

So my question is is there any grammar or writing guide for this situation?

Comment: Always cite your sources: [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Elements_of_Statistical_Learning/yPfZBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22these+two+tasks%22+%22in+particular+both+can+be+viewed+as+a+task%22&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks unidiomatic to write it like this :

> (1)  We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common, and in particular **both** can be viewed as **a task** in function approximation.

What you have given is good , though not the intended meaning in the Context here [[ thanks to user "Mari-Lou A" for including that ]] :

> (2) We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common, and in particular **both** can be viewed as **tasks** in function approximation.

Slightly better (though still not the intended meaning) is to drop the "and" & then use "Both" to start a new Sentence :

> (3) We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common [:;.] {use Colon or Semicolon or Period here} **Both** can be viewed as **tasks** in function approximation.

Even better is this (which is still not the intended meaning) :

> (4) We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common, and in particular **these two** can be viewed as **tasks** in function approximation.

The meaning is : "task1 is a task in function approximation" & "task2 is a task in function approximation" , in general.

Alternate Context can occur [[ Indeed , that is the Case here ! ]] , where we have to write it like this :

> (5) We will see that these two tasks have a lot in common, and in particular **these two** can be viewed as **a single task** in function approximation.

The meaning is : "task1 & task2 generally occur together to become a larger task3 which is a single inseparable generalized task in function approximation" , in general.

Example in general  : "Identify (x,y) values where y is maximum" is made of 2 tasks : "Identify x" & "Identify y" : Yet , it can be a single inseparable task.

Example in Context : Classification is a technique which converts Input values to Output label , while regression is a technique which converts Input values to Output value. **These two tasks** can be generalized into **a Single task** to convert Input numbers into Output function.
[[ Speaking loosely ! This is not a question concerning the technology involved !! ]]

Comment: so there's no difference btw. the first two ((1) and (2)) in your answer as I understand?

Comment: In the given Context , which user "Mari-Lou A" included , the Intended meaning is that "both" [ or rather "these two" ] can be viewed as a Single task , otherwise the claim is redundant & almost meaningless. We already know X is a task in function approx & Y is a task in function approx : It is redundant to claim that both are tasks in function approx. Instead , the writer might want to claim that "these two" are the Same Single task. In short : (2) will not mean (1) here.

Comment: Summary : (2) & (3) & (4) are similar , though not similar to (1) & (5) which are similar. I think (5) is better than (1) here : We have to high-light that the 2 tasks are actually a Single task !